# How can I differentiate between male and female Sonchafa trees?

Tags: identification, trees

I have two [Sonchafa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnolia_champaca) trees in my pot. but they are not flowering. I am told that there is a male tree and a female tree. I may have a male tree in my pot.

How can I differentiate between a male tree and a female tree?

Comment: I added a link to the Wikipedia article for [_Magnolia champaca_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnolia_champaca). Please [edit] your post   to correct that if I've linked to the wrong plant (the article indicates that the name may be used for other plants).

Comment: If you actually do mean Magnolia champaca, these plants are not separated between male and female individuals.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you can't.

Caveat:  I don't know this species in particular, but in all the diecious woody plants I know, none of them can be told apart before they bloom.  Unlike mammals, there is no consolidation of sex related genes onto a single chromosome.

(Eventually we should be able to detect differences from sequencing the DNA.  Not trivial.  Most plants have a lot more DNA than mammals, and the interactions get messy.)